# jQuery - Detecting when a user clicks OUT of an input type Text Field

Tags: jquery

I want to detecting when a user clicks OUT of an input type Text Field, not in.

Here's what I have but both events are firing on click inside (focus):

```
<input id="title" val="hello" />

$("#title").focusout(function() {
    console.log('inside');
}).blur(function() {
    console.log('outside');
});
```

Comment: `blur` is good enough for what you need. what exactly is the question?

Comment: Are you sure? They both fire for me when *leaving* the field. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j3XWM/)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your description of what is happening is opposite of what should happen for those events. Are you really saying that `focusout` and `blur` fire when clicking *inside* the input?

Comment: pretty sure `$(el).focusout().blur()` is a bad idea... but I like the concept of clicking outside of an element!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can bind your `focus` and `blur` event like so:

```
<input id="title" val="hello" type="text" />

$("#title").focus(function() {
    console.log('in');
}).blur(function() {
    console.log('out');
});
```

`focusout` isn't necessary since it's geared toward event bubbling for child elements: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 15):

You could write a little plugin, like

```
(function($){
  $.fn.outside = function(ename, cb){
      return this.each(function(){
          var $this = $(this),
              self = this;

          $(document).bind(ename, function tempo(e){
              if(e.target !== self && !$.contains(self, e.target)){
                  cb.apply(self, [e]);
                  if(!self.parentNode) $(document.body).unbind(ename, tempo);
              }
          });
      });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

..and use it like:

```
$('#title').outside('click', function(e) {
    console.log('outside');
});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/tGnun/

Comment: very clever.  Perhaps you could explain what the inner-workings do?

Comment: how can I do the same for the text box that is generated using js/jquery after page load

Answer (score 3):

It's looking like `focusout()` and `blur()` are both triggering when you click outside of the text. Try using `focus()` instead. Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKhAn/).

Comment: OP doesn't want focus. He wants the code to fire upon leaving the input.

Comment: @patrick, yes but he was stating that they both fire upon entering the input. For me they both fired when leaving (as you mentioned) so I assumed that maybe he was slightly mixed up. My jsfiddle has an alert that triggers going IN and OUT so I figured it was worth posting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you want, but here is a stab at it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script src="jquery-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<script>
    $("document").ready( function() 
    {   $("#body").click( function()
        { alert("body"); } );
        $("#input").click( function(event)
        { alert("input"); event.stopPropagation(); } );
    } );
</script>
<h2>input below</h2>
<input id="input" type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```